# Having trouble to build the GitHub repository "chordscalegenerator" written in Java/HTML

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, build

I was trying to build the following GitHub repository on Windows 10 x64:
https://github.com/plucknplay/chordscalegenerator

I have little knowledge in JAVA, but I found out that Eclipse 2023-06 and JDK 20 are needed, which I downloaded. I also added JAVA to system paths and confirmed it works. In Eclipse I added and activated jdk 20 as Installed JRE.

Now when I download the ZIP from the repository mentioned above and import it into Eclipse as Existing Projects into Workspace then 12k+ Errors and 60 Warnings appear.

From there I don't know how to continue or whether the code is buildable at all. ChatGPT 3.5 is no help as it doesn't know software or websites from after late 2021.

Can anybody of you point me in a direction that helps me to build the program?

Comment: This is far too broad for a Stack Overflow question. The github projects appear to be a set of Eclipse plug-ins [tag:eclipse-plugin] and the release downloads are Eclipse RCPs [tag:eclipse-rcp]. If you are not familiar with these it will be a lot of work to get this going.

Comment: @greg-449
I already feared that, a real shame, the lack of support from the author of the code. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Note that the "Releases" section of the site does contain complete executables which will probably run without needing to build the project.

Comment: @greg-449 The problem is that the author seems to have abandoned the project. He changed the domain for his websites but he didn't change the websites within the program code. First the program was a demo that could have been unlocked with a serial that I have. After some time the author made the program freeware so that any serial could have been entered to unlock. Now that the domain has changed the program can't be unlocked at all, saying that there is no connection.

So my plan was to rewrite the code. But since I can't even build it, I won't put much more time into that...

Comment: The project does not contain a build script; [`com.plucknplay.csg.build`](https://github.com/plucknplay/chordscalegenerator/tree/main/com.plucknplay.csg.build) looks like some post-processing. A Maven/Tycho build is missing (see [example](https://github.com/vogellacompany/tycho-example) and [tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html)). In Eclipse you should be able to open the [product file](https://github.com/plucknplay/chordscalegenerator/blob/main/com.plucknplay.csg.ui/csg.product) and use the _Eclipse Product export wizard_ to build it. Same for `site.xml`.

Comment: @howlger That sounds promising. Thank you very much.

What is your general assessment, if I may ask, Is there a serious chance to remove the "nag screen" so that the product starts in full mode or is this rather incomplete and useless part of a product?

I love the core of the app, and would even like to add features and even create a fork for everybody. It has the potential to become one of the most useful tools for musicians. And I'd give my time to learn it.

The only question left for me is, is it worth or a waste of time?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code looks well structured, at least at first glance. It might take some time, but it sounds like a great idea to me. I guess the "nag screen" is in [`com.plucknplay.csg.ui/src/com/plucknplay/csg/ui/activation/`](https://github.com/plucknplay/chordscalegenerator/tree/main/com.plucknplay.csg.ui/src/com/plucknplay/csg/ui/activation). If you have questions, use the tags `eclipse-plugin` or `eclipse-rcp` and for building `tycho`. Good luck and happy coding!